# Rounding number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have the formula: `r(n) = (9t(1+n)-10^t+1)/9 where t = lowerboundof(log10(n))`

What's the math symbol describing lower and upper bound of a non-integer positive  number?

Comment: $\lfloor \log_{10} n \rfloor$ gives greatest integer less than $\log_{10} n$

Comment: isn't that rounding the number to the nearest integer?

Comment: yes you can round it to either floor or ceiling : $\lfloor \log_{10} n \rfloor \le \log_{10} n \le \lceil \log_{10} n \rceil$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The floor and ceiling functions map a real number to the largest previous or the smallest following integer, respectively.

More precisely, $\lfloor x\rfloor$  is the largest integer not greater than $x$ and $ \lceil x \rceil$ is the smallest integer not less than $x$.

$$\lfloor x\rfloor=\max \{ n \in \mathbb{Z}: n \leq x\}$$

$$\lceil x \rceil=\min \{ n \in \mathbb{Z}: n \geq x \}$$